# VSCode says it cannot find jest.js file

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs

VSCode recently started to show some extra lines interleaved in my source files, with a `Debug` label. These lines are not part of my code, as I can see it's something the editor has inserted in the rendering of my code in between some lines.

[image]

Whenever I click on one of those (because the take the appearance of a link when I move the mouse cursor over them) I get the floating error message that can be seen in the top part of the screenshot.

The error message says:

```
Cannot find jest.js file!
```

What's this about and how can I get rid of it? It does not prevent me from using the editor, but it is annoying to have these lines randomly inserted in various places of my source code.

Comment: It's clearly from a plugin, likely for [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/). Which plugins do you have installed? Any test runners that might try to implement Jest themselves?

Comment: Yes, it is the Jest extension. I uninstall it and everything's ok. I install it back and I get the error. I'm not sure I have the time and will to investigate further. The extension doesn't give me anything I can't live without, so I'll drop it for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `create-react-app` .vscode/launch.json configuration that worked for me:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug CRA Tests",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts",      
      "args": [
        "test",
        "--runInBand",
        "--no-cache",
        "--env=jsdom"
      ],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }
  ]
}
```

Plus the following settings in my `.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
  "jest.pathToJest": "node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
}
```

Some additional references to a similar issues:

Reference:

This was the issue that fixed the problem for me:
* https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/issues/136

- https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/issues/113
- https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/issues/125
- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2709
- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/594
- [VSCode says it cannot find jest.js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575916/vscode-says-it-cannot-find-jest-js-file)